# TreeMap key values to String array

Tags: java, treemap

I am trying to add the key values from a Treemap to a String[], but i am doing something wrong and i get this: "[Ljava.lang.String;@281ec58a". Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

This is the code i'm using:

```
    TreeMap t = new TreeMap(hm); //hm is a Hashmap
    t = (TreeMap) sortByValues(t); // i sort the values with this method
    String [] tempa = (String[]) t.keySet().toArray(new String[t.size()]);
```

Comment: Could you show your `sortByValues`? I bet it's something it does.

Comment: are you sure sortByValues(t) not adding it as object? Without sortbyvalues() I am getting what ever hm key value is.

Comment: sortByValues sort the treemap. hashmap is HashMap<String, Integer>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"[Ljava.lang.String;@281ec58a"` is simply how arrays are printed (i.e. converted to a string) by default. If you iterate over the contents of the array, and print each element in turn, you'll likely find that everything is as expected.

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely unclear what the values within the `HashMap` and `TreeMap` are, because you're using the raw types. Your code would be clearer to us, you and the compiler if you used generics.

However, it could well be that everything is fine - it's just that you're converting the string array to a string somewhere by calling `toString` on it. (You haven't told us what you mean by "i get this" - where?)

Try using:

```
String output = Arrays.toString(tempa);
```

to see what the values within the array are.

Comment: thank you Jon, i can see the values now, but i need to use the String[]. i am trying to say that tempa[0] would be "blah"(a String) or "@$#$#%^"?

Comment: @emptyset: It would be "blah" - at least I'd expect it to be. It's very hard to tell what's going on with the limited information you've provided though - a short but *complete* program would really help. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: ok i am just silly. everything was ok, i've just tried to print the String[] as it was.